# ViewPager with fixed width childs

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I need to design a `ViewPager` which able to pass childs with fixed width (e.g childs with 700dp width), Unfortunately the current version of `ViewPager` will automatically makes all childrens width to `MATCH_PARENT`, is there any way to add this functionality to `ViewPager`?

My `ViewPager` layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/some_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:overScrollMode="never" />

</LinearLayout>
```

`ViewPager` childs layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/banner_main_layout_container"
    android:layout_width="700dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="some images"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: You can set this option in the VirtualHost section

Comment: @hjpotter92 Excuse me, what is the `VirtualHost`!?

Comment: Can't you change viewpager width to 700dp from match parent or to wrap_content(if that is desirable) instead of child??

Comment: @maaz This will not working since `ViewPager` measure itself to `MATCH_PARENT`.

Comment: If the viewpager child has a fixed width, then should there be extra empty space on both sides of child fragment or the next viewpager child fragment should continue from where last child fragment finished? What is the desired behaviour?

Comment: Check this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10479007/horizontal-scrollable-viewpager).

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to scale the pages within the ViewPager with `FragmentPagerAdapter.getPageWidth`. You will need a custom FragmentPagerAdapter. If you return a number between 0 and 1, the pages are scaled down, width > 1 scales pages up accordingly. But this is not really good, because you can't scroll the image within the up-scaled page.

If you wrap the ImageView in a `HorizontalScrollView`, things are a bit better, you can scroll the images within pages, but the swipe gesture between pages is caught by the HorizontalScrollView if you are not very fast. See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hgOLKuUaRKE).

So the solution is truly to use a custom HorizontalScrollView (see `InterceptingHorizontalScrollView`) which disallows intercepting the onTouch event, but also allows it when the User scrolls to the end (See overidden `onOverScrolled`). See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xZJ834UgbxA) or the image below for the difference.
[image]

**EDIT** You don't need to override onInterceptTouchEvent, because HorizontalScrollView intercepts them by default (so scrolling the image has higher priority than paging.)

Finally, here's all the code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Set up the ViewPager
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setPageMargin(30);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(new ImagePagerAdapter(getFragmentManager()));
    }

    private class ImagePagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public ImagePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int i) {
            switch(i) {
                case 0:
                    return ImageFragment.newInstance(R.drawable.forest1);
                case 1:
                    return ImageFragment.newInstance(R.drawable.forest2);
                case 2:
                    return ImageFragment.newInstance(R.drawable.forest3);
                default:
                    return ImageFragment.newInstance(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }
        @Override
        public float getPageWidth(int position)
        {
            // Here it is possible to scale page width
            return super.getPageWidth(position);
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**ImageFragment.java**

```
public class ImageFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "image_resid";
    private int mImageResId;

    public static ImageFragment newInstance(int image_resid) {
        ImageFragment fragment = new ImageFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_PARAM1, image_resid);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }
    public ImageFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mImageResId = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PARAM1);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_image, container, false);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView.setImageResource(mImageResId);
        return v;
    }
}
```

**fragment_image.xml**

```
<com.gyebro.viewpagertest.InterceptingHorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="600dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.gyebro.viewpagertest.ImageFragment">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:src="@drawable/forest1" />
</com.gyebro.viewpagertest.InterceptingHorizontalScrollView>
```

**InterceptingHorizontalScrollView.java**

```
public class InterceptingHorizontalScrollView extends HorizontalScrollView {

    public InterceptingHorizontalScrollView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    public InterceptingHorizontalScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
    public InterceptingHorizontalScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    /*@Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        if (getParent() != null) {
            switch (ev.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                    getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                    break;
            }
        }
        return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    }*/

    @Override
    protected void onOverScrolled (int scrollX, int scrollY, boolean clampedX, boolean clampedY) {
        super.onOverScrolled(scrollX,scrollY,clampedX,clampedY);
        // if clampedX == true, we've reached the end of the HorizontalScrollView so
        // allow parent to intercept
        if(clampedX) {
            Log.d("InterceptingHorizontalScrollView", "Reached the end, allowing interception");
            getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is basically the same exact answer as mine.

Comment: @PaulBurke You are missing a very important detail! You need to check `clampedX` in `onOverScrolled`, otherwise you won't be able to swipe between pages normally.

Comment: @PaulBurke What I've done here is more than just directing the user to a custom View, which does not even solve his/her problem. I've made a sample project, tried different techniques (ViewPager page scaling, plain ScrollViews in ViewPager, custom ScrollViews in ViewPager), and presented the results. Hope you agree, that I couldn't fit all these into a comment below your answer.

Comment: You've got to be kidding, right? You added `onOverScrolled` handling to the same exact class that I linked. You didn't even change the name. All of the extra code is completely unnecessary, and actually takes away from the simple answer. You took the selfish route, rather than add to my answer.

Comment: Now your answer is substantially different (and probably correct). Removed down-vote.

Answer (score 1):

What you really want here is a `HorizontalScrollView` inside of a `ViewPager`. This requires custom touch handling, so you'll want to use something like this class: [InterceptingHorizontalScrollView](https://gist.github.com/brandondenney/b8ddd655664eb295129d)

To make `InterceptingHorizontalScrollView` work in a `ViewPager`, you'll have to override `onOverScrolled`:

```
@Override
protected void onOverScrolled (int scrollX, int scrollY, boolean clampedX, boolean clampedY) {
    super.onOverScrolled(scrollX,scrollY,clampedX,clampedY);
    if(clampedX) {
        getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
    }
}
```

Thanks to Gyebro for this tip.^

Your `ViewPager` child layout would look like this:

```
<com.tumblr.widget.InterceptingHorizontalScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/banner_main_layout_container"
        android:layout_width="700dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="some images"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</com.tumblr.widget.InterceptingHorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: The `LinearLayout` here is useless, you can set the `width` and `background` of the `ImageView`

Comment: I'm not making any assumptions about the OP's layout. Only answering his question. You're assuming that this is the entire layout XML, and not just a snippet to illustrate a point. What if the OP adds addition children at runtime? Then you're approach is wrong, considering that a ScrollView takes a single child.

Answer (score 1):

You can either override PagerAdapter´s getWidth method and if this does not help, look at this:
http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/08/20/multiple-view-viewpager-options.html

and most importantly try [this example](https://gist.github.com/devunwired/8cbe094bb7a783e37ad1), it works great! 
Just go along the whole example.

Answer (score -1):

- The ViewPager children will/should always match it's parent width.
- Furthermore it sounds like a bad idea to use a 700dp width `ImageView`. What would that look like in portrait mode?

If you don't want to make the ViewPager itself smaller, i.e. you want the `ImageViews`  to be swiped from the absolute side of the screen, you have to make the items **appear** smaller.

That imitation could be done by creating 2 additional `LinearLayouts` to act as spacers. Then it would appear as if your item has a specific width.

Here's an example (with a TextView):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <LinearLayout
        android:background="#FFF"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:background="#333"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="HELLO"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:background="#FFF"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And that would look like this:
[image: ViewPager preview]

Comment: "Furthermore it sounds like a bad idea to use a 700dp width ImageView" - Instead of making assumptions about his intended goal, try to answer the question.

Comment: @PaulBurke It's not an assumption, it's an advice. If OP's code can be improved then why not help him with that too?

Comment: You're assuming the use case. Offering advice when you don't even know the context. Who said this is a consumer app displaying a photo that should be entirely visible? I'll be reporting you for down-voting my answer out of spite.

Comment: "The ViewPager children will/should always match it's parent width." -- Says who? Gmail has a ViewPager for thread view that allows the message, itself, to be scrolled horizontally. See the assumptions you're making?

Comment: @PaulBurke I don't understand your gmail example. The thread matches it's parent's (which probably is a fragment) width.

Comment: @PaulBurke I provided an alternative way, which *in my opinion*, solves the OP's problem. The OP is free to choose any answer he likes and which in **his opinion** fits his *context*. Hopefully OP will also comment on an answer that doesn't work for him.

Comment: Zoom in on a Gmail message than you'll see that you're wrong. Thread screens are a in a ViewPager, while also capable of scrolling horizontally. You down-voted my answer only because I did yours. I answered the questions.

Comment: The "OP's problem" is that he wants ViewPager children that have fixed widths, larger than their parents. How does your answer solve this at all?

Comment: @PaulBurke he didn't say anything about children width larger than that of their parents. My answer is the logical solution to what the OP is *probably* doing. We can't know for sure and *again* let's let the OP decide that instead of flaming and spamming in comments.

Answer (score -1):

Set the page margin of the view pager to a negative value. This will force the pages to push into the the view pager.  Be warned, it will also cause overlap so you'll see part of the next/previous element in the view pager.